# Best technique to add data in a database

Tags: java, android

this is my first question ever so it may not follow the rules 100% but I'll try..

So here's the question:
I'm making an app which loads some questions from a database which is stored in the device. The idea is that the first time ever the app runs on the device, a method will be called where all the data are inserted in the database. Is there a better/smarter way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on where do you get the data from and the mass of data

Comment: Are you loading from a csv file or something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) - make it create and populate the database in the **onCreate** method. SQLiteOpenHelper also makes it easier to update database structure and content when new versions of your app are released - you just need to increment the database version and implement **onUpgrade**.

Comment: yeah that is actually smarter than the thing I proposed! thanks! as you can see I'm new in android development!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an AsyncTask for not long running task or a Service if you have a lot of data to insert.

You can make a fancy SplashScreen([here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) a good one to start).

Also make sure this won't take too long, users will find it annoying.